# HTML5 video seeking to mid-video on 'ended' on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, safari

I'm using a `<video>` for a background hero video. It starts at 0:00. When it reaches the end of the 0:11 clip, it pops back to :02 and repeats from there. I've accomplished it with:

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('ended',repeatVid,false);
function repeatVid(e) {
  var mediaElement = document.getElementById('bgvid');
  mediaElement.currentTime = 2;
  mediaElement.play();
}
```

I'm only concerned with the desktop experience, since it swaps to a fallback image on tablet/mobile. This works with Chrome, Firefox, and even IE. Safari, however, repeats back from 0:00 instead of :02.

Putting the whole function on a button onclick instead of an `addeventListener` works. Reassigning currentTime doesn't appear to be the problem. I've tried putting the whole thing inside `video.oncanplaythrough = function () {`. I've tried changing the `.addEventListener('ended')` to `$('video').on('ended',function(){` or `video.onended = function () {`.

It seems like .play() always sends you back to 0:00, except I can get it to work `on('click')`, so there's something up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `play()` function in Safari seems to reset the currentTime to zero.

If you `play()` the video and set the currentTime directly after that, it works like expected:

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('ended',repeatVid,false);
function repeatVid(e) {
  var mediaElement = document.getElementById('bgvid');
  mediaElement.play();
  mediaElement.currentTime = 2;
}
```

Comment: Gosh darn it. It's always frustrating when you wrack your brain trying to find the answer and just end up needlessly overcomplicating it. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it simply needs a second pair of eyes ;-)

Comment: Same problem here. When I put the currentTime after the play(), I see the video flashing at 00:00 and afterwards jumping to currentTime. Any ideas?